# Objective-c timeIntervalSince1970 return 0

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

```
NSUInteger currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Here current time is 0.
Can you tell me reason for this?

Comment: How are you printing this ?

Comment: ```NSLog(@"%@", currentTime);```

Comment: NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: @Dan you cannot print an NSUInteger with %@

Comment: Should this be closed since the error was simply not what the title asks but the wrong use of `%@`/`%d`

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSUInteger currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
  NSLog(@"%d",currentTime);
```

this gives me correct value of current time in Milliseconds .

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSTimeInterval` instead of `NSUInteger`although `NSUInteger` is also giving the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUInteger currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"timeIntervalSince:%lu",(unsigned long)currentTime);
```

as currentTime gives a unsigned long value..